# AWS Quicksight KPI Ratios

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to calculate the closing ratio of tickets in a KPI chart. Originally, it was the last 90 days opened and closed and was calculated as:

```
distinct_countIf({CLAIM_NBR},abs(dateDiff({DATE_CLOSED},now())) <=90) / distinct_countIf({CLAIM_NBR},abs(dateDiff({DATE_OPENED},now())) <=90)
```

Now I want to switch to a comparison of the current quarter ratio compared to previous quarter ratio. I am not certain this is possible since I don't have a single time dimension for both calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant solution, but created a second variable to gather the previous 90 days.

```
distinct_countIf({CLAIM_NBR},abs(dateDiff({DATE_CLOSED},now())) >90 and abs(dateDiff({DATE_CLOSED},now())) <=180) /
distinct_countIf({CLAIM_NBR},abs(dateDiff({DT_REPORTED},now())) >90 and abs(dateDiff({DT_REPORTED},now())) <=180)
```